# Routing issue in angular

Tags: angular

For starters, I have started with angular a few days back and have found this weird issue in routing.
I imported the "RouterModule", added the path and component accordingly. Also, added router outlet to app.component.html file.
Here are my issues:

1. I can't go from one component or page to another via the navbar. For e.g. If I am on home page, I can easily go to some other page, but if I want to go to a different page and click on it's link, I automatically get redirected to the home page first.
2. All the new pages that I open still contain the complete home page code. Although, I know that it is because of adding router-outlet just on top of home page(I wrote my home page code in app.component.html), but what is a better alternative.

P.s. The questions might be too beginner level, but please bear with me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you navigate like this `<a routerlink="/contact">Contact Page</a>`. Do **NOT** use href.
2. Add another component where you add the `router-outlet`. Then you make your "home" page the default route. Ofcourse you can keep static components outside of the outlet (maybe navbar & footer?) and add those in component side by side with the `router-outlet`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

I have used routerLink only. Also, what's with this "/" symbol. I could navigate without it also. So, I think missing this might be a cause of such weird issues.

Comment: no problem. If your routerLink does not start with `/` the route will be relative to the current path. So lets say for example you are currently on `/shop/product/5`. When you would navigate with `routerLink="/home"`, you would land on your `home` route component. But when you use `routerLink="home"` you would navigate to `/shop/product/5/home`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have router configuration set up properly, for example.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "child-1", component: ChildComponent1},
      { path: "child-2", component: ChildComponent2 }
    ]
  },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" }
];
```

2. Add `router-outlet` in your app.component.html
3. In your parent component, in above example home.component.html add `routerLink` and `router-outlet` to load children,

```html
<div>
  <button routerLink="child-1">Child-1</button>
  <button routerLink="child-2">Child-2</button>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```